# How to set axis starting point to 0 for google material line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I tried multiple solutions given out from
[How to set Axis step in Google Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104925/how-to-set-axis-step-in-google-chart), [Trying to set y axis to 0 in google charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640286/trying-to-set-y-axis-to-0-in-google-charts), and several other posts that I have looked over without any luck. Does anyone have an idea of what can be done in order to set the y axis to a starting point of 0?  I can provide more information if need be. Also a side question, is it possible to bring a line to the front when clicked on. For example when you click on the current trend line, it bolds but the data points do not appear for them.

```
<div id="thelinechart" style="width: 1000px; height: 550px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script>google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();data.addColumn('string','Year');
data.addColumn('number','Current Trend');
data.addColumn('number','2015 Projection');
data.addColumn('number','2016 Projection');
data.addColumn('number','2017 Projection');
data.addColumn('number','2018 Projection');
data.addRows([
['2015',250,250,null,null,null],['2016',200,300,200,null,null],['2017',200,310,230,200,null],['2018',290,340,320,280,290],['2019',null,370,350,360,290],['2020',null,null,430,470,390],['2021',null,null,null,520,440],['2022',null,null,null,null,450]
 ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Capacity',
          subtitle: 'in weight'
        },
        width: 850,
        height: 450,
vAxis: {
        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
          //max: 8000,
          min: 0,
        },
        gridlines: {
          count: 18,  //set kind of step (max-min)/count
        }
      }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('thelinechart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
```

I have a jsfiddle link where I have my code. 
https://jsfiddle.net/abufr36y/

Comment: The updated jsfiddle link with the corrected answer: https://jsfiddle.net/abufr36y/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to convert options for Material Charts, depending on the package...

`google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options)`

See following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['line']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string','Year');
  data.addColumn('number','Current Trend');
  data.addColumn('number','2015 Projection');
  data.addColumn('number','2016 Projection');
  data.addColumn('number','2017 Projection');
  data.addColumn('number','2018 Projection');
  data.addRows([
    ['2015',250,250,null,null,null],['2016',200,300,200,null,null],['2017',200,310,230,200,null],['2018',290,340,320,280,290],['2019',null,370,350,360,290],['2020',null,null,430,470,390],['2021',null,null,null,520,440],['2022',null,null,null,null,450]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Capacity',
      subtitle: 'in weight'
    },
    width: 850,
    height: 450,
    vAxis: {
      viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
      viewWindow: {
        //max: 8000,
        min: 0,
      },
      gridlines: {
        count: 18,  //set kind of step (max-min)/count
      }
    }
  };

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]);

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('thelinechart'));

  // convert options for Material Charts, use view vs. data
  chart.draw(view, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="thelinechart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. @WhiteHat When the line is brought forward, say you click on 'Current Trend', the line is theickened and everything else is hidden. But when you hover over the data point, you don't get to see the Current Trend information. For example hover over the 2015 data point, and you get 2015 Projection instead of Current Trend.

Comment: i see what you mean -- see edit -- you can use a view to change the position of the column, which "brings the points forward", but then the points from the other lines don't show when you hover over them...

Comment: That was perfect, I updated my code to include the setting the columns dynamically since I load the data dynamically. I always include the 2nd column in the last position of the array. Thanks for the help.